# How can I add text to a list element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, performance

I am a new programmer and I recently started following a music-player tutorial, and I am experiencing a couple of issues with it.

**Project Overview:**

As previously described, it is a music-player project made with `create-react-app`. The objective is to click the image of the song of your choosing, and for the song to be played for you.

**The Problem:**

As of right now,  the **clickable images** are listed on the **left side**  of the **music-player page**, in turn, leaving a big chunk of the page empty. This space is still a list component, the Idea is for it to be filled with the title of the song it corresponds to. However I have no idea how to do it. **How would I be able to add their respective titles to the list?**

#### The Code

**Turkish.js** *(music-player file)*:

```
import React, { Component,useRef, setStatus, status } from 'react';
import './Turkish.css';

import turk1 from "./music/turk1.mp3";
import turk2 from "./music/turk2.mp3"
import turk3 from "./music/turk3.mp3"
import turk4 from "./music/turk4.mp3"

export default function Turkish() {
    const data = [
        { imgSrc: 'turk1.png', audioSrc: turk1},
        { imgSrc: 'turk2.png', audioSrc: turk3 },
        { imgSrc: 'turk3.png', audioSrc: turk4 },
        { imgSrc: 'turk4.png', audioSrc: turk2 },
    ];

    return (
        <div className='Turkish'>
            <ol>
            
                {data.map(({ imgSrc, audioSrc }) => (
                    <MediaComponent imgSrc={imgSrc} audioSrc={audioSrc} />
                ))}
            </ol>
        </div>
    );
  
}

const MediaComponent = ({ imgSrc, audioSrc }) => {
    const audioRef = useRef(null);
    const toggleAudio = () =>
      audioRef.current === null
        ? console.log("Audio component is not loaded yet.")
        : audioRef.current.paused
        ? audioRef.current.play()
        : audioRef.current.pause();

        
    return (
        <ol>
            <img src={imgSrc} onClick={toggleAudio} />
            <audio
                ref={audioRef}
                src={audioSrc}
                onLoad={() => setStatus({ ...status, isLoaded: true })}
                onPlay={() => setStatus({ ...status, isPlaying: true })}
                onPause={() => setStatus({ ...status, isPlaying: false })}
                onError={() => setStatus({ ...status, error: true })}
            />
        </ol>
    );
};
```

**Turkish.css**

```
.Turkish ol {
    cursor: grab;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #303030;
    border-width: 0.01px ;
    border-left: transparent;
    border-right: transparent;
    border-bottom: transparent;
   
}
```

Below I've attached an **image of the design.**

[image]

Comment: First, you need to get the names of the songs as data. As near as I can tell by your code, you don't have that information.

Comment: Add more properties like title, artist in to each object in data list, then you can read them from the .map() function and pass them to MediaComponent as props. Same as you pass the imgSrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add more properties as you needed into each object of data list;

```
const data = [
    { imgSrc: "turk1.png", title: "Track One" },
    { imgSrc: "turk2.png", title: "Track Two" },
    { imgSrc: "turk3.png", title: "Track Three" },
    { imgSrc: "turk4.png", title: "Track Four" }
  ];
```

Then you can read them through .map() and pass them to MediaComponent as props;

```
<div className="Turkish">
  <ol>
    {data.map(({ imgSrc, audioSrc, title }) => (
      <MediaComponent imgSrc={imgSrc} audioSrc={audioSrc} title={title} />
    ))}
  </ol>
</div>
```

Inside MediaComponent replace your element "ol" by "li" and render title as a prop;

```
return (
    <li>
      <img src={imgSrc} onClick={toggleAudio} />
      <div>{titile}</div>
      {/* <audio
        ref={audioRef}
        src={audioSrc}
        onLoad={() => setStatus({ ...status, isLoaded: true })}
        onPlay={() => setStatus({ ...status, isPlaying: true })}
        onPause={() => setStatus({ ...status, isPlaying: false })}
        onError={() => setStatus({ ...status, error: true })}
      /> */}
    </li>
  );
```

You can use CSS Flexbox Layout for styling;

```
.Turkish ol li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: grab;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #303030;
  border-width: 0.01px;
  border-left: transparent;
  border-right: transparent;
  border-bottom: transparent;
}
```